# Inject angularjs module into angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a module in angularjs:  `angular.module('ivh.treeview').`

In angularjs I could add it in container like this:

```
angular.module('tree', ['ivh.treeview']);
```

How I can use this module `ivh.treeview` in angular2? How I can add this in DI container?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add one Module to another with angular2,You could just add the Module to the root Module like this,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        whateverModule
]
```

Comment: but added module is module on angularjs. i think it's a problem.

Comment: You cannot do that

Comment: i added like @NgModule({ imports: [ ['ivh.treeview']] and in console appeared error : Error: Unexpected value 'ivh.treeview' imported by the module 'Module'

Comment: Why do you want to do.that?

Comment: because i have module on angularjs which I can not rewrite on angular 2 fast, but need it )))

Comment: You should rewrite it